# equality of Addresses fails even if all fields are identical

Tags: java, unit-testing, equality

I created an `Address` class like below,Then I wanted to check equality of two `Address`es.If all the fields are identical,the two `Address`es are considered identical.

So,I implemented the `hashCode` and `equals` methods.

```
public class Address{

    public String addressLine1;

    public String addressLine2;

    public String city;     

    public String state;

    public String pincode;

    public String phoneNumber;      

    public String country; 

    public Address() {

    }

    public Address(String addressLine1, String addressLine2, String city,
            String state, String pincode, String phoneNumber, String country) {         
        this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
        this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.pincode = pincode;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = prime * result
                + ((addressLine1 == null) ? 0 : addressLine1.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((addressLine2 == null) ? 0 : addressLine2.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((city == null) ? 0 : city.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((country == null) ? 0 : country.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((phoneNumber == null) ? 0 : phoneNumber.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((pincode == null) ? 0 : pincode.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((state == null) ? 0 : state.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("equals("+obj);
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!super.equals(obj))
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Address other = (Address) obj;
        if (addressLine1 == null) {
            if (other.addressLine1 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!addressLine1.equals(other.addressLine1))
            return false;
        if (addressLine2 == null) {
            if (other.addressLine2 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!addressLine2.equals(other.addressLine2))
            return false;
        if (city == null) {
            if (other.city != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!city.equals(other.city))
            return false;
        if (country == null) {
            if (other.country != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!country.equals(other.country))
            return false;
        if (phoneNumber == null) {
            if (other.phoneNumber != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!phoneNumber.equals(other.phoneNumber))
            return false;
        if (pincode == null) {
            if (other.pincode != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!pincode.equals(other.pincode))
            return false;
        if (state == null) {
            if (other.state != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!state.equals(other.state))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.addressLine1+","+this.addressLine2+","+this.city+","+this.state+","+this.pincode+","+this.country+","+this.phoneNumber;
    }

}
```

In the TestCase for this class ,I tried to create two identical addresses and calls assertEquals..This fails however..

class AddressTests extends UnitTest {

```
@Test
public void testAddressEquality() {
    Address address1 = new Address();
    address1.addressLine1 = "#1000,South Avenue";
    address1.state = "New York";
    address1.country = "U.S";
    System.out.println("address1="+address1);

    Address address2 = new Address();
    address2.addressLine1 = "#1000,South Avenue";
    address2.state = "New York";
    address2.country = "U.S";
    System.out.println("address2="+address2);

    assertEquals(address1,address2);

}
```

}

assertEquals fails

```
Failure, expected: models.Address<#1000,South Avenue,null,null,New York,null,U.S,null> but was: models.Address<#1000,South Avenue,null,null,New York,null,U.S,null>
```

Can someone help me understand why this failed?

Comment: Have you stepped through the test in a debugger to find out which line fails?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion..I found that 'if (!super.equals(obj))
   return false;' is the line which returns false..Is this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem:

```
if (!super.equals(obj))
        return false;
```

`Object.equals` checks if the references are the same (same test as your `this == obj` test). You don't want that check there at all - you've already tested for reference equality, and you do not want to bail out if the object references are not the same.

Form [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

One implementation ([OpenJDK](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Object.java.html)):

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  return (this == obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also modify your hash function.  Why not just take the sum of the other hash values?  The way you have it, the result exceeds 2 billion (Integer.MAX_VALUE) if most of the fields are not null, so you wrapping around the integer values.

Answer (score 0):

You should **never ever create hashCode/equals manually**... let your IDE of choice do it for you.

In IntelliJ IDEA its simplly ALT+Insert, generate hashCode/equals. Eclipse would be somehow similar.